# MOBILE FFMPEG filter complex with yup420 output issues

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I am creating video by images using mobile-ffmpeg using complex-filter and format yuv420, I am having problem width is not divisible by 2(601*900) like so.
**This error is occuring for some video creations for many it is working fine.**
My filter complex is scaling, rotating and overlaying the input images.
Here is ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 10 -i background.jpg -s 700x900 

-loop 1 -i img1.png -loop 1 -i img2.jpg 
-loop 1 -i img3.jpg

-filter_complex
[1]scale=eval=frame:w='72':h='72'[img1];
[2]scale=eval=frame:w='598':h='382',rotate=a=0*PI/180:c=black@0:oh='roth(0*PI/180)':ow='rotw(0*PI/180)':bilinear=1,fade=in:st=2:d=3:alpha=1[img2];
[3]scale=eval=frame:w='598':h='382',rotate=a=0*PI/180:c=black@0:oh='roth(0*PI/180)':ow='rotw(0*PI/180)':bilinear=1,fade=in:st=3:d=4:alpha=1[img3];
[0][img1]overlay=W-w-5:5:format=auto:shortest=1:format=auto[bg1];
[bg1][img2]overlay=44:500:shortest=1:format=auto[bg2];
[bg2][img3]overlay=44:22:shortest=1:format=auto,format=yuv420p" 

output.mp4
```

Having some searches about it and found -vf filter can adjust the width:height but it is restricted not to use with filter-complex...

My error logs:

```
 E/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xbd8c8800] 
 E/mobile-ffmpeg: width not divisible by 2 (601x901)
 E/mobile-ffmpeg: Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a scale before the format.

```
scale=w=bitand(iw,65534):h=bitand(ih,65534),format=yuv420p
```

Comment: I am finiding this error in logcat:: Unable to find a suitable output format for 'scale=w=bitand(iw,65534):h=bitand(ih,65534),format=yuv420p', can you please where this scale is to be added in my command... within filter complex. kindly edit the given command. Thanks

Comment: Insert the scale filter before the `format=yuv420p` in your command.

Comment: hi sir, I want some knowledge could I use a gif to start of command previously I had done with -loop 1 -t 10 -i background.jpg now want replacement with -y -ignore_loop 0 -t 30 -i background.gif.... I had tried it but it not scalling or overlaying properly... images going out od -s 600, 700...